# weblogic/spring app make server URI redirect to context-root

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, uri

I have a spring app built with maven and hosted on WebLogic server with a context-root of /myApp.  To access the app you must enter the URL: myserver:7001/myApp.  Is there any way to keep the context root at /myApp, but when a user goes to https://myserver:7001 they are redirected to https://myserver:7001/myApp?  The Spring app is a single page app, using index.html as the base of the page so I can't (or havent been able to) successfully use a welcome-page to redirect to the context-root.

Comment: did you search? see [this link](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=886)

Comment: Yes, I've searched and searched.  I tried the supplied link both options just change the context-root to /.  I would like to keep the app accessible at /myApp and also make it accessible at /.  I was thinking the solution would be a redirect from / to /myApp, but the examples I've seen doing that don't seem to work either.

Comment: If you install apache httpd then you can do a reverseProxy